# overlapping background images of nested div

Tags: php, html, css

have background images in nested divs as follows

```
<div id="templatemo_content" style="padding: 30px 30px 0 0; background: #fff url(images/foot_bg.png) no-repeat 0 bottom; z-index:10">
this div has grey colored background image
<div style="background:url(images/job.png) no-repeat 0 0; height:131px; z-index:5">
this is a nested div with another background image having right bottom overlapping grey colored image
</div>
</div>
```

below image is what i have achieved so far, however, expected image is the 2nd one below[image: overlapping-bg-img]

[image: expected-image]

used z-index to both images however browsing through internet found that z-index does not work on background images. please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`z-index` is relative to the parent container from which `z-index` is set. As such, a child cannot have a lower `z-index` than its parent in terms of displaying below it.

You may want to change your HTML

```
<div>
    <div>this is a nested div with another background image having right bottom overlapping grey colored image</div>
    <div>this div has grey colored background image</div>
</div>
```

CSS (will require some alteration)

```
div {
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    height:131px;
}
div:first-child {
    background:url(images/job.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    margin-top:30px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
div:last-child {
    background:url(images/foot_bg.png) no-repeat 0 bottom;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set

```
    position: relative;
```

Thus, the z-index will - should - be effective.